# macOS Calendar pushes, doesn't pull? iCloud & iPhone push & pull

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, calendar, mojave

My iCloud Calendar appears to be working (from any web browser). My iOS Calendar appears to be working (from my iPhone). My macOS Calendar appears to be pushing changes to iCloud, but not pulling changes from iCloud:

- If I create, edit, or delete an event on iCloud.com, it immediately appears on my iPhone, but not on my Mac.
- If I create, edit, or delete an event on my iPhone, it immediately appears on iCloud.com, but not on my Mac.
- If I create, edit, or delete an event on my Mac, it immediately appears on iCloud.com, and on my iPhone.

Also:

- If I click Menubar / View / Refresh Calendars, changes still aren't pulled to my Mac.
- If I change Menubar / Preference / Accounts, Refresh Calendars from "Push" to "Every minute", and wait a minute, changes still aren't pulled to my Mac.
- Waiting overnight and over days doesn't fix the issue.
- Only if I quit macOS Calendar app and relaunch the app, then changes are pulled to my Mac.

This problem only appeared after replacing a 2011 "High Sierra" MacBook Pro with a 2018 "Mojave" Macbook Air. I've tried signing in/out of iCloud everywhere. I've wiped and rebuilt the machine. I've spent hours on the phone with Apple, to no avail. Any help, please?

- macOS 10.14.2 Mojave
- iOS 12.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it takes a couple of minutes to sync.

Can you try what you see here:
Open the Calendar app, choose Calendar > Preferences, On the General tab, make sure that one of your iCloud calendars is the default.

Comment: I've waited overnight and over days. Under macOS Calendar / Prefs / General, "Default calendar app" is set to "Calendar". The only other option is "Select…".

Comment: What I gather from your OP is that iPhone up and down works fine. iCloud web, up and down works fine. macOS down is the problem. This has nothing to do with 2011 or 2018 MacBooks. More of a software issue. Try using this app called Onyx. What it does is, it clears the caches and temporary files. You also say that you rebuilt the machine which should have totally solved the issue but didn't. After you rebuilt, did you use any backup to restore? If that was the case, maybe the preferences file was restored, thereby leading to you having issues again.